# Does node have a way to consume/stop an event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I'm looking for a way to add events such that they fire sequentially and *optionally* pass through.  I'm wondering if there is anything like this natively in the Node API, or if not if anyone knows of a decent npm package that accomplishes this:

```
obj
  .on('event-A', function(){
    // log something()
    // consume or stop the event
  })
  .on('event-A', function(){
    // this never fires
  });
```

Comment: Sorry about assuming when I saw the `.on`. I'm not greatly familiar with node but if there are no inbuilt solutions then, are events _frozen_ or _sealed_? If not, you could add a _cancelled_ property to check for. Extending this, you should change `events.EventEmitter.prototype.on` to check for _cancelled_ as well.

Comment: @PaulS. -- No worries, we all make mistakes :)  Unfortunately there isn't an "event" created when you trigger an event, so there's nothing to piggy-back on.  It just passes through whatever arguments.  e.g. `.trigger('a', 'b')` will call `handler('a', 'b')`, _not_ `handler(ev, 'a', 'b')` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a library ([event-chains](http://npmjs.com/event-chains)) that replicates the `EventEmitter` API and provides cancelation via either rejected promises or by calling `this.stop()`.  Also steals an idea from `signals` where you can have "single event" emitters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any node-api allowing to cancel event dispatching. But you can take any node-compatible event library (node, pubsubjs, etc) and modify the dispatching function with these guidelines:

- pass a cancel function to your event listener as a this/first/last (pick up the one you like the best) parameter. That cancel function will have a cancel property in a closure, that your event dispatcher will check prior to dispatching events.

But note that:

- as this is a side-effect, this can make your program a bit harder to reason about. You will have to keep in mind all the places where the side-effect occurs to completely understand you program. Also, your event handlers have to be executed sequentially, which means you must have a consistent definition of order (order of registering listeners, user-defined order?).

Comment: Thanks, already re-wrote the `EventEmitter` API in a similar fashion.

Comment: yes, just saw your previous message now. I was also thinking that the functionality you are looking for is similar to the middleware used for instance in express.js, where you pass a function next to handlers, which they have to call to transfer the flow to the next handler. But I guess you are looking more to signal an end of flow than to signal a continuation.

Comment: For others who might find this pattern interesting, I quote here an example of library that allows you to create your own middleware mechanism : https://github.com/segmentio/ware, or the ES-6 (uses generator functions) more sophisticated https://github.com/thenables/composition. Once your middleware chain is defined, you wrap it up in a listener to the event you are interested in. You then define only one listener instead of several as in the regular approach.

Comment: yeah, I was trying to decide which direction made more sense (rejecting vs continuing), and ended up with the rejection pattern because it's the way promises work.  I just layered the emission chains on top of a Promise.